# php and greek characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I have this script which takes the `Fname` from a HTML form. When I insert Greek characters, the name of the folder is displayed with symbols in Windows Explorer. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

```
$folderStr = $_REQUEST['FName'];

//create SEO firndly directory name
$upload_folder =    preg_replace ("'\s+'", '-', $folderStr);

// The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).
 $upload_path = './uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/';

//Check whether folder exists or create with the name supplied

if(is_dir($upload_path))
echo 'directory exists';
else
mkdir ('./uploads/'.$upload_folder.'/', 777);
```

Comment: Isn't this really a Windows file system issue that may be caused by what PHP outputs?

Comment: I usually avoid the usage of non ASCII chars in a folder name or URLs when working on PHP. I have a set of substitution function that i.e. translate ƒ into f.

Comment: Apparently, Windows NTFS uses [`UTF-16`](http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/filesystem-encoding-and-php) (scroll down to the Windows section).

Comment: And what should i add to my code so encode the non-ASCII characters to UTF-16?

Comment: $filename = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE", $input_string);

Comment: from this line: $folderStr =  $_REQUEST['FName'];
i write it like this: $folderStr =  iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE", $_REQUEST['FName']);
But it doesn't make the folder anymore. :/

Comment: @StavrosBackwards : Like Napolux wrote. Don't do this. Strip out all special characters. If you plan to make a downloadlink to these files, they should only cintain ASCII characters and nothing else. Or you may break the download for some people.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the form you are submitting from is utf-8 encoded.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```